# How to discriminate between initializing and no-user states in Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Auth's email authentication in web.

Is there a way to discriminate between initializing (has created user once but does not yet
fetch auth information in this time) and no-user (has not even created user) states?

Answer (score 1):

No, the API doesn't expose that data.  A user is either:

- fully signed in
- fully signed out
- unknown if anyone was ever signed in or out (at app launch)

That "unknown" state is due to the fact that the process to determine if a user was previously signed in is asynchronous.  After init happens, there is a period of time required by the SDK to load any tokens and contact Firebase Auth to determine if they are valid.  Unfortunately, the API doesn't itself expose the fact that it sees a previous token, the user account represented by that token, or if the validation/refresh failed.

You basically have to wait for the auth state listener to tell you if the user is definitely signed in or out in order to know anything for sure.  Until then, your app is stuck in that "unknown" state (unless you want to try to find and load that token yourself somehow, which is an SDK implementation detail).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Maybe I should wait a/few seconds before other requests which depend on auth states. (This implementation may brings on worsening user experiences...)

Comment: Typically, you make the rest of the app wait for the listener to tell you for sure what the user state is.  Using a hard coded delay is sure to cause problems.

Comment: Understood! `auth.onAuthStateChanged` callback is called when the client confirms that there is no user and in that case the callback's argument is null. I made a mistake that the callback is not called.  Thank you!